# How to select elements from a table that are present in a junction table with LINQ - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables:

- Book : id - title - etc
- BookInstance : id - column - row - etc
- BookBookInstance (junction) bookId - bookInstanceId - Id

I want to retrieve the bookinstances for a book and i get a book ID as a parameter. How do i do that? I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project i can either use LINQ or anything given by C#, but i would love to see the SQL query as well so i can learn :)

```
public List<BookInstance> GetBookInstancesForBook(string bookId)
    {
        using (var db = new LibraryDataContext())
        {
            // Any solutions?         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should there really be a many-to-many relationship between `Book` and `BookInstance`?  I would think you'd just have a `bookId` in `BookInstance` giving you a one-to-many relationship instead.

Comment: Yes i think i made a mistake there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
var bookInstances = db.BookBookInstance.Where(x => x.BookId == bookId)
                      .Select(x => x.BookInstance).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? (may need some tweaking since I dont have your entity models - the include may need to be singular depending on the object model)

```
public List<BookInstance> GetBookInstancesForBook(string bookId)
{
    using (var db = new LibraryDataContext())
    {
        var results = (from b in db.Books
            .include("BookBookInstances")
        where b.ID == bookID
        select b.BookInstances        
       ).ToList();
    }
}
```